# Oracle BITAND equivalent of Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle

I would like to create an index using BITAND function. Oracle version is working fine. I want to convert that into Postgres. I realized that a similar question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581445/is-there-an-equivalent-to-oracles-bitand-function-in-postgres). But it does not mention the second Postgres version. Which is the best way to define an index?

Oracle:
`create index index_name on table (BITAND(ROLE, ROLE));`

Possible Postgres versions:

1 - `create index index on table ROLE & ROLE));`

2 - `create index index on table (BITAND(ROLE, ROLE)); //same with Oracle`

Comment: This all depends on which of those two expressions you use in your query. The expression in the query needs to match the expression in the index to make the optimizer consider the index.

Comment: But I don't see the point in the index. If you do a bitwise `and` of a value with itself, this is the same as the value,  so `role & role` is the same as `role`

Comment: So if same expressions are used in both creating index and also while querying will be a good solution? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Can I use BITAND while creating index, and & during queries?

Comment: It's the same rules as in Oracle.